# Configure Apache to pull SNI certificates for HTTPS from a database rather than from the filesystem configured in a virtual host

Tags: apache, dynamic, https, sni

I'm setting up a redirect server where users can input an alternate domain name, point DNS to my server, and configure it to redirect to their servers.  My plan is to use the default virtual host in Apache to handle all the requests, route everything to a web application that looks up the place to redirect in a database.

I'd like to support HTTPS, but I can't figure a way to dynamically specify the certificate and key for each site.   The only way that I know of configuring HTTPS is by putting directives for SSH certs and keys into a virtual host specific to that domain name.   I'd like to store the certificates and keys in the database along with the domain name and have Apache call my web app during the SNI handshake.

Is it possible to have flexible, dynamic SNI under Apache?